# Missing Parameter in POST request - Need help finding source

Tags: python, json, post, get, http-headers

I'm looking for a value. It is a session ID.

I analyzed network activity and the only reference to such a thing is "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-site-sessionid"on a request response header.

I also found it at the end of the POST request (sessionid=xxxx) but I need that value beforehand so my script can work. On my browser it does it automatically but I've been unable to find the value's source or how to request it from the site.

How would I pull this value? Everything else with the script is working as I tested it with an old session ID (that I got from a post request in my network activity log) and it registered fine. Though this isn't ideal for multiple runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameters that appear in the url address are not POST parameters , you simply need to add the session_id that your receive in the OPTIONS request to the url of the POST , like so:

```
session_id = 'get options response'
request.post(url + "&sessionid=%s" % session_id, data = {})
```

Comment: Thank you! Understood. Well, the options request doesn't actually provide a value. Just mentions it by name in the "Access-Control-Allow-Headers:" portion of the response headers. Unsure of what type of request will actually pull this information. If you've got a few minutes I'd gladly compensate